# Adding cdn stylesheets and javascripts in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hi I cannot add fontawesome to my nuxt app I have try adding it in the nuxt.config.js and it still does not seem to work.

```js
head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/leap-icon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', ref: 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css' }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 15):

Below is the correct method to implement external resource in nuxt.

```
link: [{ rel:"stylesheet", type:"text/css", href:'http://www.example.com/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' }]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think just changing `type` to `href` should fix it. e.g.

```
  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css' }
```